# What is the thevenin voltage and resistance of the circuit given below

Tags: thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2qR7H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thevenin equivalent is defined between a pair of the circuit nodes. You need to define those, otherwise the question makes no sense.

Comment: R1, R2 and R3 are in parallel to a voltage source, you can neglect them.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified where you are looking from.

I will assume Its RL.

So first step is to calculate the Thevenin voltage.

Remove RL  Now the current I1 must flow through R5 the voltage across R5 with RL removed is therefore

$$0.2A \times 16 \Omega = 3.2V$$

That's added to V1 to give

$$Thevenin Voltage = 3.2V + 2.4V = 5.6V$$

Now for Thevenin Resistance:

Short all voltage sources, open all current sources and calculate the resistance you would see across RL which in this case is just R5

$$Thevenin Resistance = 16 \Omega $$

If you want to find the voltage across RL its just:

$$Vth \times \frac {RL}{Rth + RL}$$

You can use similar techniques to solve for any other pair of nodes.

---

To clarify what Thevenin actually said that for a circuit consisting only of DC sources and resistors you can simplify the circuit from the view point of any two nodes into a resistor and a voltage source.

Lets take a simple example:

[image]

We are tasked to find the voltage across R4.  This isn't too difficult even without Thevenin but we can use Thevenin to simplify things if we were to remove R4 then there would be no current in R3 and we can easily calculate the output voltage.  This is the Thevenin voltage Vth.

$$Vth = Vth \times \frac{R2}{R1+R2} = 6V \times \frac{6k}{3k+6k} = 4V $$

Now we want to calculate the Thevenin resistance.  So we replace all the sources, in our case there is only one, with their output impedances and an ideal voltage source has zero impedance thus R1 and R2 are effectively in parallel.  So the Thevenin reistance (Rth) is

$$Rth = \frac{R1 \ R2}{R1 + R2} + R3 = 2k + 3k = 5k$$

So we now have our Thevenin equivalent circuit with R4 removed

[image]

We can reconnect R4 and this is a simple potential diver

$$ Vout = Vth \times \frac{R4}{Rth+R4} = 4 \times \frac{1k}{5k+1k} = \frac{4V}{6} = 0.66V$$

Note: The Thevenin voltage only apply from a particular pair of nodes; if we chose another pair we could still calculate but would get different answers.

This method can also be applied to AC circuits providing we only consider sine waves and replace capacitors and inductors with the complex impedance they have at the frequency of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.You've been a great help to me in solving this problem.

Comment: You already have the formula for VL.  IL = VL/RL and PL = VL * RL.

Comment: I have this formula where PL=IL to the power 2*RL which will equal to (VTh/RTh+RL)to the power 2*RL. can i apply this equation to find the power of the load resistor

Comment: PL = VL * IL = (VL^2)/RL = RL * IL^2.  Any of these work